# How to resolve these linking errors while installing ffmpeg?

Tags: linux, installation, fedora, ffmpeg

I downloaded ffmpeg installation using git:

> [FFmpeg Git](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html)
>
> There are Git repositories of FFmpeg and libswscale. Both are kept in sync with SVN automatically. To allow building FFmpeg with libswscale, the libswscale directory must be present inside the FFmpeg directory. They can be cloned with the commands:

```
git clone git://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg/
cd ffmpeg
git clone git://git.ffmpeg.org/libswscale/
```

Now when I try to do a `./configure`, this is what I get:

```
./configure: line 631: libswscale/libswscale.pc: No such file or
> directory
> rm: cannot remove `libswscale/libswscale.pc.tmp': No such file or
> directory
```

Now I Googled and found this http://www.mail-archive.com/blfs-dev@linuxfromscratch.org/msg08856.html which suggests some solution, but I am confused what to do, as it talks about svn and I am using git.

**How can I resolve this dependency?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was a known bug with that release. Got a different release and it installed fine.